personal start in enumerate inside newlist
With newlist, I defined an "exercise" list which starts from 1 and goes on in the natural way (2, 3, 4...).
What I would like is to modify the code in order to start it from 0.1 and go on like 0.2, 0.3 and so on UNTIL I change the subsubsection (or, if not possible, the subsection).
So on the second subsubsection (which should be labeled by 1 because the very first one is the zeroth) the exercises list start with 1.0, 1.1, and so on... Here is the code I used so far.
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}

\usepackage[bb=stixtwo]{mathalpha} 


\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{dr}{rgb}{0.84, 0.09, 0.41}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{everysel}
\everymath{\color{dr}}
\everydisplay{\color{dr}}
\EverySelectfont{\color{black}}

%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor, cleveref}


\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercise,1]{wide=0pt,
        label=\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\arabic*.}}}
%%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{arsenic}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Zeroth subsubsection}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]

\item First item token. 
\item So the following exercises.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 0.1)
\item second exercise (should be 0.2)

\end{exercise}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection ONE}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 1.0)
\item second exercise (should be 1.1)

\end{exercise}


\end{document}


Thank you so much for your help!
EDIT
Thanks to @cfr that managed to improve a lot the code! Yet there is still some problem (perhaps it's my compiler?).
The parts of the code @cfr wrote that I used are these:
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercise,1]{wide=0pt,
label=\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\arabic{subsubsection}.    \arabic*.}}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{-1}

With this part, and the following code
\section{new section}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{-1}
\subsubsection{Zeroth subsubsection}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]

\item First item token. 
\item So the following exercises.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 0.1)
\item second exercise (should be 0.2)

\end{exercise}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection ONE}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 1.0)
\item second exercise (should be 1.1)

\end{exercise}


\end{document}

What I get is this:

Which is almost perfect for what I wanted, except for the fact that I don't want those numbers in subsubsections. I would like to have 0 as the number-label in the first subsection and 1 in the second subsection. Instead there is 0.1.0 in both...
ANOTHER EDIT
Modifying a bit, I came up with this solution, which might be ugly.
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\subsubsection*{0. Zero}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]

\item First item token. 
\item So the following exercises.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 0.1)
\item second exercise (should be 0.2)

\end{exercise}

\subsubsection*{1. Random}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{1}
\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 1.0)
\item second exercise (should be 1.1)

\end{exercise}

Obtaining


why have you defined \subsubsection to use the subsection counter the same as \subsection (and why load color and the xcolor twice

after your edit you are still not numbering subsubsections so you don't have a number to reference in the lists.  You should use \subsubsection after \subsection but in your first fragment you use it as the top level section and in the second you use it after \section it's not possible to get any kind of sensible output if the input does not follow any structure

@DavidCarlisle I understand, but I don't need sections not subsection. Also, I tried to add \subsection before \subsubsection and the result was nothing. Subsubsection number changed to 0.0.0, nothing else

@DavidCarlisle Ok I managed to find a way. Going to edit the question to show what I tried, even it might be aberrant.

sorry that makes no sense. If you only need one section level you need \section  you can use titlesec to make that use a smaller layout don't just use a 3rd level heading disable its numbering, specify it should use the numbering of the unused 2nd level heading and expect to get any kind of sensible output. The fact that you get a pdf at all is just the result of lack of error checking.

@don't put solutions in to questions, you can post a self answer

@DavidCarlisle You're right, but I was not confident enough. As I said, it might be ugly... But in case I will

why does the exercise in the first section start at 0 (0.0 an d0.1) but the exercise in the second section start at 1 (1.1 and 1.2)  ??? how would you number an exercise in the third section???

@DavidCarlisle No, 0 and 1 are the subsubsections (or the sections). The enumerate part was just a try to remove. You can then see that 0 section leads to 0.1, 0.2 et cetera; section 1 leads to 1.1, 1.2 and so on and section 2 will lead to 2.1, 2.2 and so on (if that was what you meant)

You wrote "should be 0.1" for the first item in section 0 and "should be "1.0" for the first item in section 1. My answer did not do that, as it didn't seem to make sense and I could not guess what rule that was implementing.

@DavidCarlisle Oh, well that was by bad :D I forgot to edit that part

your document class sets secnumdepth to 2 so subsubsections are not numbered so there is no increment of the subsubsection counter. You had defined \subsubsection to show the subsection counter. This is why you were apparently getting an initial value of zero because you were showing a subsection counter when there had been no subsections.
If you set secnumdepth to 3 and make \subsubsection use the subsubsection counter, it becomes a lot clearer.

\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\definecolor{dr}{rgb}{0.84, 0.09, 0.41}


\usepackage{everysel}


\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercise,1]{wide=0pt,
        label=\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic*.}}}
%%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{arsenic}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{black}}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}


\subsubsection{Zeroth subsubsection}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]

\item First item token. 
\item So the following exercises.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 0.1)
\item second exercise (should be 0.2)

\end{exercise}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection ONE}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 1.0)
\item second exercise (should be 1.1)

\end{exercise}


\end{document}

If you want the section counters to start from 0 instead of 1 that can be arranged, but at all levels or just subsubsection? (I would not like to guess as the requiremnt is rather strange either way)

Update
In comments you clarified you do only want one section level and do want it to start from 0 so you should not be using \subsubsection at all.

\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}




\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\definecolor{dr}{rgb}{0.84, 0.09, 0.41}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\the\numexpr\c@section-1\relax}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}


\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercise,1]{wide=0pt,
        label=\textbf{\textcolor{black}{\thesection.\arabic*.}}}
%%

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{black}}{}{0em}{}

\begin{document}


\section{Zeroth section}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]

\item First item token. 
\item So the following exercises.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 0.1)
\item second exercise (should be 0.2)

\end{exercise}

\section{Section ONE}

\begin{exercise}

\item first exercise (should be 1.0)
\item second exercise (should be 1.1)

\end{exercise}


\end{document}


Thank you for this. I edited the question referring to the other user who answered but his answer is vanished... Anyway, yes what I would like is for the exercise list under the first subsection (which should be numbered only as 0, not 0.0.0.1) to start from 0.1 (going on 0.2, 0.3 and so on), then the exercise list of subsubsection 2 (that is 1) should be 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and so on...
Notice that I want to skip elements 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 and so on

@Henry I updated my answer.

Thank you!! That is very limpid indeed!
